# Javascript won't interact with html code

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

The code is written in JSP that should validate password and confirm password correctness and then continue the submit event to the Java servlet. But the problem is that it won't show the alert messages nor focusing on the password input if it fails the validation script. I've used chrome, explorer and Eclipse default browser.. just won't work

```js
function validate(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,32}$/;
  var pwd = document.form.password.value;
  var confPwd = document.fomr.confPass.value;
  if(pwd.match(pattern)){
   alert("Password must be between 8 to 32 characters,\n have at least one digit \n two lower and one upper case letters.");
    document.form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }else if(pwd == confPwd){
    alert("Passwords do not match. Please try again.");
    document.form.password.focus();
    document.form.confPass.focus();
    return false;
  }else{
    document.form.submit();
  }
 }
```

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="RegisterPath" onSubmit="return validate(event);">
  <table class="box">
    <tr>
      <td class="left">Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">Confirm Password:</td>
     <td><input type="password" name="confPass" placeholder="Re-enter password" required/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `if(pwd == confPwd)`: shouldn't that be `if(pwd != confPwd)`? Also, `document.fomr`, is `fomr` just a typo?

Comment: Also `document.fomr.confPass.value` is a typo that would prevent the rest of the function from running.

Comment: Client side password validation is a security loop hole. Someone could copy your page and remove the javascript that validates the password. If you are doing client side validation, make sure you also do it server side.

Comment: just convert your password value to toUpperCase(); and compare it.

Comment: Using `if(pwd.match(pattern))` as you do, aren't you saying that it isn't valid if it matches? Isn't that the opposite of what you want?

Comment: @khAn Is that a joke? So passwords `abc123` and `ABC123` would validate as identical?

Comment: If this is actually a copy-paste of your script, you would do well to learn about the developer tools available [in](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/) [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console) [modern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182326(v=vs.85).aspx) [browser](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/).

Comment: @msanford,  we can use in else if block to check the condition.

Comment: @khAn *Absolutely not.* Why would you do that? The point of this is to confirm that both strings entered were identical, and your suggestion would break that, for example `"abc123".toUpperCase() === "ABC123"`.

Answer (score -1):

This working code will help you.

```js
function validate(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var pattern = /^(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z\d]{8,32}$/;
  var pwd = document.form.password.value;
  var confPwd = document.form.confPass.value;
  if (!pwd.match(pattern)) {
    alert("Password must be between 8 to 32 characters,\n have at least one digit \n two lower and one upper case letters.");
    document.form.password.focus();
    return false;
  } else if (pwd != confPwd) {
    alert("Passwords do not match. Please try again.");
    document.form.password.focus();
    document.form.confPass.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    document.form.submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form" method="post" action="RegisterPath" onsubmit="return validate(event);">
  <table class="box">
    <tr>
      <td class="left">Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">Confirm Password:</td>
      <td><input type="password" name="confPass" placeholder="Re-enter password" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: to validate form as u have added attribute 'required'

Comment: But also, no it won't because `else if (pwd == confPwd) {alert("Passwords do not match}`...